# Javascript variable, define if not defined

Tags: javascript

**How to define a variable only if not defined?** The check seems easy enough, but then the block part should look something like this:

```
if (typeof PersonalDataForm !== "undefined") {
    alert("foo defined!");
} else {
    var foo = {};
}
```

Now, if I know my JS, that var foo statement will get *separated* in `var foo` at the beginning of the function scope and `foo = {}` inside the block itself, because JS lacks block level scope variable definition. So it will always be undefined, won't it?

A run of this code proves it (it always prints "foo undefined"):

```
var foo = {};

function checkFoo() {
    if (typeof foo == "undefined") {
        console.log("Foo undefined");
        var foo = "default";
    } else {
        console.log("Foo defined");
    }
}
checkFoo();
console.log(foo);
```

An interesting case for using this could be the declaration of a personal "library", which starts with:

```
var myOwnLibrary = (function () {
    //...code...return object with public methods...blablah
})();
```

unless it's already defined, in which case it prints an error.

Comment: `foo = foo || 'default'`?

Comment: @kyll what if foo's value is **falsey**?

Comment: Ah, right. `foo = typeof foo !== 'undefined'? foo : 'default'`. But it gets boring to read. And, of course, it fails if `foo`'s value is `undefined`. Last way to do it might be to try and use `foo`, and see if there's a `ReferenceError` thrown I guess.

Comment: @kyll wouldn't that dinamically create a function scope `foo` variable?

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure why you are using **typeof** operator.

After removing it is working as expected.

```
var foo = {};

function checkFoo(){

    if(foo == "undefined"){
        console.log("Foo undefined");
        var foo = "default";
    }else{
        console.log("Foo defined");
    }
}

checkFoo();
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: it's working because `{} !== "undefined"`, but if you remove the `var foo = {};` line, it still prints "foo defined" because `foo` is not defined and that's not equal to the string "undefined" 

https://jsfiddle.net/bLztaus8/1/